# keras sequential model returning loss: nan

Tags: python, neural-network

I am trying to implement an artificial neural network in python using 'keras'. The problem I am facing is that my model is returning the 'loss: nan' for every epoch. I want to mention that the dataset that I have used from the csv file has a column with some missing values. I would like to asked if is this 'nan' is due to these missing data? and is there any way to get a numerical value of loss intead of 'nan'?
following is my code,

```
# Importing the Keras libraries and packages
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

# Initialising the ANN
classifier = Sequential()

# Adding the input layer and the first hidden layer
classifier.add(Dense(6, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim = 7))

# Adding the second hidden layer
classifier.add(Dense(6, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))

# Adding the output layer
classifier.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'sigmoid'))

# Compiling the ANN
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

# Fitting the ANN to the Training set
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 10, epochs = 100)

# Part 3 - Making the predictions and evaluating the model

# Predicting the Test set results
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
y_pred = (y_pred > 0.5)

# Making the Confusion Matrix
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
print(cm)
```

following is the output I got,

```
Epoch 1/100
72/72 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6299
Epoch 2/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6133
Epoch 3/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.5996
Epoch 4/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6477
Epoch 5/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6131
Epoch 6/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6256
Epoch 7/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.5933
Epoch 8/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.5806
Epoch 9/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6123
Epoch 10/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6342
Epoch 11/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.5910
Epoch 12/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6151
Epoch 13/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.5999
Epoch 14/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.5828
Epoch 15/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6317
Epoch 16/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.5782
Epoch 17/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6085
Epoch 18/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6383
Epoch 19/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6102
Epoch 20/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.5944
Epoch 21/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.5966
Epoch 22/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6168
Epoch 23/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6010
Epoch 24/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.5946
Epoch 25/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6586
Epoch 26/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6527
Epoch 27/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6222
Epoch 28/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6322
Epoch 29/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6211
Epoch 30/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6261
Epoch 31/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6164
Epoch 32/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6242
Epoch 33/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.5785
Epoch 34/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6115
Epoch 35/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6290
Epoch 36/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.5886
Epoch 37/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6225
Epoch 38/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6109
Epoch 39/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.5951
Epoch 40/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6126
Epoch 41/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6096
Epoch 42/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6146
Epoch 43/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6031
Epoch 44/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6232
Epoch 45/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6403
Epoch 46/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6068
Epoch 47/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6126
Epoch 48/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.5879
Epoch 49/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6173
Epoch 50/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6379
Epoch 51/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6323
Epoch 52/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6202
Epoch 53/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.5956
Epoch 54/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6069
Epoch 55/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6090
Epoch 56/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6400
Epoch 57/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6293
Epoch 58/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6008
Epoch 59/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6422
Epoch 60/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6270
Epoch 61/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.5997
Epoch 62/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.5959
Epoch 63/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6409
Epoch 64/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6185
Epoch 65/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6096
Epoch 66/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6240
Epoch 67/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6176
Epoch 68/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.5958
Epoch 69/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.5994
Epoch 70/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6375
Epoch 71/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6238
Epoch 72/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6214
Epoch 73/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6147
Epoch 74/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6046
Epoch 75/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.5876
Epoch 76/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6085
Epoch 77/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6265
Epoch 78/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.5964
Epoch 79/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6177
Epoch 80/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6143
Epoch 81/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6093
Epoch 82/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6162
Epoch 83/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.5974
Epoch 84/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6151
Epoch 85/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6304
Epoch 86/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6148
Epoch 87/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6224
Epoch 88/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6076
Epoch 89/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6228
Epoch 90/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6203
Epoch 91/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6431
Epoch 92/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6258
Epoch 93/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6425
Epoch 94/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6436
Epoch 95/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6318
Epoch 96/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6273
Epoch 97/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6230
Epoch 98/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.5846
Epoch 99/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.5866
Epoch 100/100
72/72 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6027
[[110   0]
 [ 69   0]]
```

The values of X_train are as follows,
[X_train values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLXFN.png)

Comment: What happens when you replace missing values for zeros? It would be good to show how `X_train` looks like

Comment: Ok I got the loss value now after replacing NaNs by 0 but is it the right way  to do?

Comment: Right, that's the issue. You should always avoid inputting NaNs - any mathematical operation involving a NaN value results in a NaN value (and the loss function directly depends on `X_train`). Replacing NaNs by 0 is a common way to tackle missing values (not necessarily the best - it depends on your specific problem). There are other ways to tackle this (e.g. you can google "data imputation strategies" to find more about this).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments section, the issue is that your input dataset `X_train` contains NaNs. Since any mathematical operation involving a NaN value results in NaN (and the loss function directly depends on X_train) your loss also ends up being NaN.

To overcome this issue, you can *impute* the missing values. For example, replacing NaNs with 0 is a common way to tackle missing values (though not necessarily the best). Another typical choice is to impute NaNs with the mean or median value of the corresponding feature. In any case, you can always see what works best via the validation loss.